# Grass error during script

Tags: grass-gis, error

I've got a serious problem with the following Grass error:

```
r.in.ascii -si input=srsaviLC815173.asc output=srsaviLC815173 --o --q
WARNING: closecell: can't move
     C:\Users\bla\Documents\grassdb/utm32/PERMANENT/.tmp/4732.1
     to cell file
     C:\Users\bla\Documents\grassdb/utm32/PERMANENT/fcell/srsaviLC815173
```

The weird thing is that the same action has been performed already several times with no error. Has anyone got a hint where this comes from?

Comment: That is a Warning and not an error. Do you have any results of your action?

Comment: Indeed, it's a warning. Well, the next step is vectorizing the raster. This is also done, but afterwards (when exporting the vector table to csv) the script stops with the error: `ERROR: Unable to open vector map <srsaviLC815173@PERMANENT> on level 2. Try to rebuild vector topology by v.build.`

Comment: Is perhaps your disk full?

Comment: Thank you @markusN. Well, there are only 11GB left, but my disk is not full (I run my script with files that have only few KB, so this shouldn't be a too big issue...). Do you see a problem in the remaining disk space?

Comment: No, 11GB is certainly fine.